# Image downloader for a website

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, web-scraping

This code takes a website and downloads all .jpg images in the webpage. It supports only websites that have the `<img>` element and `src` contains a .jpg link.

([Tested here](https://pixabay.com/))

```
import random
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def Download_Image_from_Web(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    raw_text = r'links.txt'
    with open(raw_text, 'w') as fw:
        for link in soup.findAll('img'):
            image_links = link.get('src')
            if '.jpg' in image_links:
                for i in image_links.split("\\n"):
                    fw.write(i + '\n')
    num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('links.txt'))
    if num_lines == 0:
        print("There is 0 photo in this web page.")
    elif num_lines == 1:
        print("There is", num_lines, "photo in this web page:")
    else:
        print("There are", num_lines, "photos in this web page:")
    k = 0
    while k <= (num_lines-1):
        name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
        fullName = str(name) + ".jpg"
        with open('links.txt', 'r') as f:
            lines = f.readlines()[k]
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(lines, fullName)
            print(lines+fullName+'\n')
        k += 1

Download_Image_from_Web("https://pixabay.com")
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4):

#### Unnecessary file operations

This is horribly inefficient:

> ```
> k = 0
> while k <= (num_lines-1):
>     name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
>     fullName = str(name) + ".jpg"
>     with open('links.txt', 'r') as f:
>         lines = f.readlines()[k]
>         urllib.request.urlretrieve(lines, fullName)
>         print(lines+fullName+'\n')
>     k += 1
> ```

Re-reading the same file `num_lines` times, to download the k-th!

Btw, do you really need to write the list of urls to a file?
Why not just keep them in a list?
Even if you want the urls in a file,
you could keep them in a list in memory and never read that file, only write.

#### Code organization

Instead of having all the code in a single function that does multiple things,
it would be better to organize your program into smaller functions,
each with a single responsibility.

#### Python conventions

Python has a well-defined set of coding conventions in [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/),
many of which are violated here.
I suggest to read through that document,
and follow as much as possible.

Comment: list doesn't work form me, it  separates each link in one list and i don't know how to merge those links in one lists;

Comment: @SalahEddine perhaps you're looking for the `extend` function, for example `all_links.extend(links)`

Comment: please look at it now I have solved some problems

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162160/image-downloader-for-a-website-v2

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the things others mentioned, you can also improve the way you locate the `img` elements that have `src` attribute ending with `.jpg`. Instead of using `findAll` and if conditions, you can do it in one go with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for img in soup.select("img[src$=jpg]"):
    print(img["src"])
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# got from http://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317
def download_file(url):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-1]
    print("Downloading {} ---> {}".format(url, local_filename))
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
    return local_filename

def Download_Image_from_Web(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for link in soup.findAll('img'):
        image_links = link.get('src')
        if not image_links.startswith('http'):
            image_links = url + '/' + image_links
        download_file(image_links)

Download_Image_from_Web("https://pixabay.com")
```

Comment: it works pretty good, i feel bad about my code lol

Comment: I learned quite a lot from this code thank's for shairing it