# Image downloader for a website v2

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

This code takes a website and downloads all .jpg images in the webpage. It supports only websites that have the img element and src contains a .jpg link. The previous version can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/162123/image-downloader-for-a-website)

```
import random

import urllib.request

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def Download_Image_from_Web(url):
    # variables
    k = 0
    links_list = []
    # source code to BeatifulSoup
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    # filtering
    for link in soup.findAll('img'):

        image_links = link.get('src')
        if '.jpg' in image_links:
            for i in image_links.split("\\n"):

                links_list.append(i.split())
    # send image links and download them
    while k <= (len(links_list) - 1):
        # create a random name
        name = random.randrange(1, 1000)
        fullName = str(name) + ".jpg"
        # download each link sperated
        lines = links_list[k][0]
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(lines, fullName)

        print(lines)
        print(fullName + '\n')

        k += 1
# choose a site that has the <img> element in its html source code with src tag
Download_Image_from_Web("https://pixabay.com")
```

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel. Website scraping is a well-solved problem: `wget --accept jpg,png http://example.com`. Additional flags like recursive as you need. Note that neither `wget` nor your work-in-progress will get anything inserted into the page with javascript, and that's very common these days.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a lot to improve about your code, and I'll start from the top. I'll also rewrite some of the logic you had there because IMO it's a bit clumsy and hard to understand.

---

#### Imports

Don't use `urllib` and `requests` at the same time. Use either one or another. They serve the same purpose.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import random
import requests
```

As you can see, I've alphabetically ordered them so that it becomes easier to locate each of them.

---

#### Constants

You have one `url` which might be moved at the top of your program. That way, you'll allow your users to change it without searching through all the code.

Moving on, I realised that you didn't give the user a chance to save the pictures wherever he wants. Let's add another constant, say `IMAGE_LOCATION`.

```
URL = 'https://pixabay.com' 
IMAGE_LOCATION = '/home/images/'
```

---

#### Functions

You can split your code into separate functions so that each of them can serve its own purpose. Read more about [Single Responsability Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle):

```
def get_html_source():
    """Docstring here."""
    html_source = requests.get(URL).text
    return BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
```

The above function will return a `BeautifulSoup` object which contains the html source code of the desired `URL`.

We can now build another function which will generate a path containing a random name for each picture we're downloading:

```
def image_name():
    """Docstring here."""
    return '{}.jpg'.format(os.path.join(IMAGE_LOCATION, str(random.randrange(1, 100000))))
```

I've also increased the maximum number just in case there's a huge number of files.

Another helper function would be one that checks if a `src` URL is a valid one or not. I've modified a bit your condition and made it more strict:

```
def validate(image_url):
    """Docstring here."""
    return image_url.endswith('.jpg') and image_url.startswith('http')
```

The above, verifies if the url starts with `http` (implicitly `https` will pass) and also if it ends in `.jpg`.

Only now, we can finally create the `download_images` function, and wrap our logic into it:

```
def download_images(soup):
    """Docstring here."""
    for link in soup.find_all('img'):
        image_url = link.get('src')
        if validate(image_url):
            image = requests.get(image_url)
            if image.status_code == 200:
                with open(image_name(), 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(image.content)
```

As you can see, I've removed most of the logic you had, and simply did the following steps:

1. Go through all the `img` tags and save their `src` attribute (which is an URL
2. Check the URL if it matches our condition and *build* our image object
3. Double check to see if the status code was successful (200) and save the image to our desired location.

Next, wrapping all our code within a main function is as simple as:

```
def main():
    """Docstring here."""
    soup = get_html_source()
    download_images(soup)
```

---

#### All the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import random
import requests


URL = 'https://pixabay.com'
IMAGE_LOCATION = '/home/images/'


def get_html_source():
    """Docstring here."""
    html_source = requests.get(URL).text
    return BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')


def image_name():
    """Docstring here."""
    return '{}.jpg'.format(os.path.join(IMAGE_LOCATION, str(random.randrange(1, 100000))))


def validate(image_url):
    """Docstring here."""
    return image_url.endswith('.jpg') and image_url.startswith('http')


def download_images(soup):
    """Docstring here."""
    for link in soup.findAll('img'):
        image_url = link.get('src')
        if validate(image_url):
            image = requests.get(image_url)
            if image.status_code == 200:
                with open(image_name(), 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(image.content)


def main():
    """Docstring here."""
    soup = get_html_source()
    download_images(soup)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you don't know what's with `if __name__ == '__main__'` you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

More, note that all the functions have a [*docstring*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) which contain a placeholder like "*Docstring here.*". You can replace that placeholder with a summary that describes what each function does.

Comment: Your otherwise good answer is kind of ruined by the `"""Docstring here."""` lines. Either write a proper docstring, or leave it out. As it stands it is a screaming reminder of something to do, which isn't done.

Comment: thank you so much for this great explanation, I have a long way to go I've just started coding and your advises were surely helpful!

Comment: @holroy However, people who would Google, find this and copypaste the code from the accepted answer would still have to do something with the code (most likely), which is positive.

Answer (score 10):

- Do not use capitalization for function or variable names. This violates idiomatic python naming conventions ([PEP8 link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names)). Try out [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) to catch these kinds of issues
- Prefer `str.format()` over concatenation. `str.format()` is not only a lot more flexible, but easier to use than concatenation and more efficient for combining more than 2 strings. With `str.format()` you do not need to explicitly convert objects to the string type (less `TypeError` exceptions). Instead of `str(name) + ".jpg"` do `"{}.jpg".format(name)`
- Prefer [iteration over indexing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-pythonic). A `list` or any container can be iterated over to yield its contents. For example do `for link in links_list:` instead of `while k <= (len(links_list) - 1):`
- Use sub functions to break up your code to improve readability and decrease complexity. Splitting up your code into logical pieces also improves testability and reusability. This function is on the larger side.

---

Randomly picking a filename is decidedly not a good idea. The given filename may already exist, and urlretrieve will go ahead and overwrite the file.

Here's a function for retrieving a unique filename:

```
from itertools import count
import os


def unique_filename(base_dir="", fail_cond=os.path.exists):
    """Yield a unique filename.

    Args:
        base_dir:
            Directory path to yield filepaths from and check
            for existing files. Should already be created.
        fail_cond:
            Function to call to check if the given filename
            should be yielded. Must return a bool value.
            If the function returns false for the given filename
            then the given filename will be yielded

    The given filenames start at 0.jpg, 1.jpg and so on
    """
    pathfmt = os.path.join(base_dir, "{}.jpg")
    for filenum in count():
        filepath = pathfmt.format(filenum)
        if not fail_cond(filepath):
            yield filepath
```

You could still randomly pick a filename, however I would still check if that filename already exists to stop overwriting. When you pick random numbers there is some chance that a number may appear in the same program run. A program is not robust if it steps on its own toes by potentially overwriting files it just downloaded.

You could use this generator in the main function:

```
for link, filename in zip(links_list, unique_filename()):
    urllib.urlretrieve(link, filename)
```

We use a generator to yield only filenames that do not exist, and use the finite `links_list` to limit the generator since `zip` stops when the first iterable is exhausted.

As a side note, `links_list` is a very redundant name. A list implies multiple but so does the pluralization `links`. I (and [Brandon Rhodes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YklKUuDpX5c)) would rather name it `link_list`. If this was ruby, you would want to just name it `links`.

---

Lets pull out the link finding code into its own function.

```
def image_links(soup):
    """Yield src tag jpg urls from given BeautifulSoup object."""
    for link in soup.findAll('img'):
        image_links = link.get('src')
        if '.jpg' in image_links:
            for i in image_links.split("\\n"):
                yield i.split()[0]
```

I do have a suspicion that some of these splits are not needed. Also indexing the first element of each list in `links_list` (from your code) belongs here, since it's an implementation detail of finding the links from an html source tree.

---

We can also pull out the html tree object creation code into its own function:

```
def get_soup(url):
    """Get BeautifulSoup object from given url.

    Does not do any error checking.
    """
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    return BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
```

---

Bringing these functions together we get an easier to understand main function:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request


def download_images_from_page(url):
    """Download jpg images from html at given url to the local filesystem.

    The use the cwd for the location of the downloaded images."""
    soup = get_soup(url)
    notify_fmt = "{url}\n{filename}\n"
    for link, filename in zip(image_links(soup), unique_filename()):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, filename)
        print(notify_fmt.format(url=link, filename=filename))
```

Note: I did not do error checking and exception handling, since the other answer covers that appropriately. I think the best solution would be some combination of mine and @MrGrj's answer.

Also make sure your imports are at the top like @MrGrj's in the actual document.

Comment: I'm new to the coding world and and I'm really thankful for the time you've given for this great explanation, thank you so much Sir!